# How change the color of header GroupItems in PropertyGrid?

Tags: wpf, propertygrid, resourcedictionary, xceed

I use in my app the PropertyDataGrid (Xceed Extended Toolkit for WPF) and ResourceDictionary with the Themes of my programm. 
The DarkTheme has white TextColor and I have white text on white background in the header of itemgroup.
I changed the color of text of name of PropertyItems by using this code, but I don't know, how change font color of group header.

```
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type xceed:PropertyItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BlackBrush}"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
         </Style>
```

[problem header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IthHV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the TextBrush key in the Resources section of the PropertyGrid:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBrush" Color="Blue" />
```

Funk helped me find the answer; see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487407/wpf-extended-toolkit-propertygrid-change-font-color-in-rows-and-search-box).

BTW, I tried your solution to the PropertyItem Forecolor problem, but it didn't work for me.  What did work was:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
```

in the Resources section of my PropertyGrid