# WPF Extended Toolkit PropertyGrid: Change font color in rows and search box

Tags: wpf, propertygrid, mahapps.metro

I am using the WPF Extended Toolkit PropertyGrid in a WPF app which also uses MahApps.

I have set the application theme to `BaseDark`.

When I display PropertyGrid, the text in the first column of the grid and in the Search textbox is white on a white background.

I would like to change the `Foreground` color of this text to black.

I have tried applying this `Foreground` color to various target controls (i.e. `TextBlock`, `TextBox`, `DataGridCell`) in `PropertyGrid.Resources.Style` but this has not changed these particular texts.

What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the appropriate Keys in the [MahApps Colors](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Colors.xaml) section, TargetTypes through elimination

```
<pg:PropertyGrid.Resources>
    <!--TextBox-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBrush" Color="Black" />
    <!--Label-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LabelTextBrush" Color="Black" />
    <!--TextBlock-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="Black" />
<pg:PropertyGrid.Resources/>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what worked: <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />